# How to solve for $x$ from $x + \ln(x) = \ln(c)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, closed-form, lambert-w

How do I solve this equation for P? For everything I've tried, P ends up trapped in an exponent or another natural log.

$$ \ln\left(\frac{GC}{a}\right) = hP + \ln(P) $$

Comment: There isn't an elementary solution.  You need to use things like [Lambert's W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Solving_equations).

Comment: We cannot rearrange the equation for $P$ by only applying only finite numbers of only elementary functions/operations to the equation. The reason is described in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586412/how-can-we-show-that-az-ez-and-alnz-z-have-no-elementary-inverse/4586413#4586413

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution will involve the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

The title question is the definition:
$$
x + \ln x = \ln c
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
xe^x = c
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
x = W(c)
$$
For the more complicated question...
$$
\ln\left(\frac{GC}{a}\right) = hP + \ln(P)
\\
\frac{GC}{a} = Pe^{hP}
\\
\frac{hGC}{a} = hPe^{hP}
\\
W\left(\frac{hGC}{a}\right) = hP
\\
\frac{1}{h}W\left(\frac{hGC}{a}\right) = P
$$