# Closed-form solution of the following equation:

Tags: closed-form

I'm looking for a closed-form solution for $x$ in the following equation:

$(v^2 - 3x^2)\cdot \ln(\frac{1}{x}) - 2x^2 = 0$,

where $v$ is a constant $ \in [0, 1]$ and $ 0 \leq x \leq v $.

I thought about using the Lambert $W$ function, but couldn't transform the equation into the correct form.

Solving the problem numerically with a computer is no problem; see the graph below. On the horizontal axis are the different values of $v$; on the vertical axis, the solutions $x^{*}$.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaUSa.png)

In case it helps, here's a table of some $(v, x^{*})$ pairs:

| $v$ | $x^{*}$ |
| --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0$ |
| $0.25$ | $0.12556794085822331$ |
| $0.5$ | $0.23849380900899855$ |
| $0.75$ | $0.34035742432223576$ |
| $1$ | $0.43122112794123896$ |

Comment: How about setting $w=v/x$ so $\log w = \log v + \frac{2}{w^2-3}$ ? This gives a reasonable numeric solution: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ln+w%3D%282%2F%28w%5E2-3%29%29 + the constant shift $\log v.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.)**

$$(v^2-3x^2)\ln(\frac{1}{x})-2x^2=0$$
$x\to\frac{1}{x}$:
$$(v^2-\frac{3}{x^2})\ln(x)-\frac{2}{x^2}=0$$
$$v^2x^2\ln(x)-3\ln(x)-2=0$$
We see, your equation is related to an equation whose left-hand side is a function term that is an algebraic expression of both $x$ and $\ln(x)$. Liouville and Ritt proved that such kind of functions doesn't have elementary inverses: [How can we show that $A(z,e^z)$ and $A(\ln (z),z)$ have no elementary inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586412/how-can-we-show-that-az-ez-and-a-ln-z-z-have-no-elementary-inverse/4586413#4586413)
That means we cannot solve the equation for $x$ by rearranging it by only applying finite numbers of only [elementary functions/operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) which we can read from the equation and apply them from the left to the left-hand side and the right-hand-side of the equation.
But if the equation has solutions that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number), is another mathematical problem.

**2.)**

$$(v^2-3x^2)\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-2x^2=0$$
$$v^2\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-3x^2\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-2x^2=0$$
$x\to e^\frac{t}{2}$, $\forall t,x\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$\left(\frac{3}{2}t-2\right)e^t-\frac{1}{2}v^2t=0$$
$$\left(\frac{3}{2}t-2\right)e^t=\frac{1}{2}v^2t$$
$$\frac{3t-4}{v^2t}e^t=1$$
$$\frac{t-\frac{4}{3}}{t}e^t=\frac{1}{3}v^2$$

We see, we have the variable $t$ in a non-linear rational expression. We cannot apply Lambert W therefore. But we can apply a Generalized Lambert W:

$$t=W\left(^\frac{4}{3}_{\ 0};\frac{1}{3}v^2\right)$$
$t\to 2\ln(x)$:
$$2\ln(x)=W\left(^\frac{4}{3}_{\ 0};\frac{1}{3}v^2\right)$$
$$x=e^{W\left(^\frac{4}{3}_{\ 0};\frac{1}{3}v^2\right)}$$

We have a closed form for $x$ and the representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

See the references below.

[Mezö 2017] Mezö, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mezö/Baricz 2017] Mezö, I.; Baricz, A.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Answer (score 0):

Your equation can be rearranged as
$$\begin{align}
\ln(x) &= \frac{2x^2}{3x^2-v^2} \\
x &= \exp \left(\frac{2x^2}{3x^2-v^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

This doesn't look to me like something that would have a nice closed form. Mathematica's `Solve` and `Reduce` functions both fail to make any progress even on the slightly simplified version
$$\begin{align}
\ln(x) &= \exp \left(\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}\right).
\end{align}$$
This makes me expect there is no satisfying closed form. I'd be glad to be proven wrong though!