# Solving $x=\frac{2^{1+y}}{\left(y+1\right)\left(y+2\right)}$ for $y$

Tags: functions

Do you know how to solve the following equation to make $y$ the subject:
$$x=\frac{2^{1+y}}{\left(y+1\right)\left(y+2\right)}$$

My attempts:
I multiplied both sides by $\ln(2)(y+1)^2$ to get
$$x\ln\left(2\right)\left(y+1\right)^{2}\left(y+2\right)=\ln\left(2\right)\left(y+1\right)e^{\ln\left(2\right)\left(y+1\right)}$$
The reasoning behind this was to get an expression of the form $xe^x$ to use the Lambert W function. However I was unable to make it work. I also tried considering the more general function
$$x=\frac{z^{1+y}}{\left(y+1\right)\left(y+2\right)}$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to z cancels the $(y+1)$ term in the denominator which I thought could make it easier to work with. However again I was unable to find a solution.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: May be expanding the power of 2 as a series?

Answer (score 1):

$$x=\frac{2^{1+y}}{\left(y+1\right)\left(y+2\right)}$$

Let $t=(y+1)$ and rewrite it as
$$e^{-t \log(2)}=\frac{1}{t (t+1) x}$$
which has a formal solution in terms  of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$). The only problem is that the solution will be given as an infinite sum of Laguerre polynomials.

Back to the original problem, assuming $x>0$, consider that we look for the zeros of function
$$f(y)=\frac{2^{1+y}}{\left(y+1\right)\left(y+2\right)}-x$$ which shows a minimum value since
$$f'(y)=\frac{2^{y+1}}{\left(y^2+3 y+2\right)^2} \Big( y^2 \log (2)+y (3\log (2)-2)+(2\log (2)-3)\Big)$$ has a positive root around $y_*=1.46958$ where $$f(y_*)=\frac{e^{1+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4+\log ^2(2)}} \log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{2}
   \left(2+\sqrt{4+\log ^2(2)}\right)}-x$$ So,

- if $x< 0.646424 $, no solution
- if $0.646424 \leq x \leq 1$, two solutions
- if $x >1$, one solution.

Considering the last case, notice that looking instead for the zero of function
$$g(y)=\log \left(\frac{2^{y+1}}{(y+1) (y+2)}\right)-\log(x)$$ is easier since it is close to a straight line and this is very good for any root-finding method.

If the problem was
$$\frac{2^{y+\frac{3}{2}}}{\left(y+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}=x \sqrt 2$$ it would be very simple. This can be justified by the fact that $y$ will always be larger than $4$ and that
$$\frac{1}{(y+1) (y+2)}-\frac{1}{\left(y+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{4 y^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{y^5}\right)$$

This provides a quite good estimate
$$y_0=-\frac 3 2-\frac 2{\log(2)}W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{2 \sqrt[4]{2} \sqrt{x}}\right)$$ Using a couple of Newton iterations to polish the root will be more than sufficient.

A table of results for $x=10^k$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 k & y_0 & y_1 & \text{solution} \\
 0 & 3.8262288 & 3.7981910 &  3.7979745 \\
 1 & 9.1465586 & 9.1421901 &  9.1421849 \\
 2 & 13.447526 & 13.445525 &  13.445524 \\
 3 & 17.454761 & 17.453577 &  17.453576 \\
 4 & 21.311032 & 21.310238 &  21.310238 \\
 5 & 25.073470 & 25.072897 &  25.072897 \\
 6 & 28.771329 & 28.770894 &  28.770894 \\
 7 & 32.421776 & 32.421434 &  32.421434 \\
 8 & 36.035817 & 36.035539 &  36.035539 \\
 9 & 39.620957 & 39.620727 &  39.620727 \\
 10 & 43.182561 & 43.182368 &  43.182368 \\
 11 & 46.724604 & 46.724439 &  46.724439 \\
 12 & 50.250118 & 50.249975 &  50.249975 \\
 13 & 53.761469 & 53.761345 &  53.761345 \\
 14 & 57.260545 & 57.260435 &  57.260435 \\
 15 & 60.748873 & 60.748775 &  60.748775 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x=\frac{2^{1+y}}{(y+1)(y+2)}$$
$$x=\frac{e^{\ln(2)(1+y)}}{(y+1)(y+2)}$$
$y\to t-1$:
$$\frac{1}{t(t+1)}e^{\ln(2)t}=x$$

We cannot read from the equation how to invert it by [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function):
[How can we show that $A(z,e^z)$ and $A(\ln (z),z)$ have no elementary inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586412/how-can-we-show-that-az-ez-and-a-ln-z-z-have-no-elementary-inverse)

We see, as already stated in the other answers, this equation isn't solvable by elementary functions and [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). But it is solvable by elementary functions together with Generalized Lambert W.

$$t=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}W\left(^{\ \ \ \ \ \ -}_{0,-\ln(2)};\frac{x}{\ln^2(2)}\right)$$
$$y=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}W\left(^{\ \ \ \ \ \ -}_{0,-\ln(2)};\frac{x}{\ln^2(2)}\right)-1$$

[Mezö 2017] Mezö, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mezö/Baricz 2017] Mezö, I.; Baricz, A.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Answer (score 0):

*I prefer to make a second answer for the generalization of the problem.*

We want to solve for $y$ the general equation
$$\color{red}{\large x=\frac{z^{a+y}}{\prod_{k=1}^n\left(y+b_k\right)}}$$ where $x$ is supposed to be large.

As in my first answer, the rhs will be approximated as
$$\frac{z^{a+y}}{(y+c)^n}=z^{a-c} \frac{z^{y+c}}{(y+c)^n}\quad \implies \quad
x\,z^{c-a}=\frac{z^{y+c}}{(y+c)^n}$$ which gives, as an *approximation*,
$$\color{blue}{\large y_0=-c-\frac{n}{\log (z)}\,W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (z)}{n\,z^{\frac{c-a}{n}}}\,\,\frac 1{\sqrt[n]x }\right)}$$

As usual, to stay in the real domain, the requirement is
$$\frac{\log (z)}{n\,z^{\frac{c-a}{n}}}\,\,\frac 1{\sqrt[n]x } \leq \frac 1 e$$

The only problem left is to decide about $c$. In the first answer was used the mean of the $b_k$'s; this is justified by the fact that, at least for large $y$,
$$\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^n\left(y+b_i\right)}-\frac{1}{(y+c)^n}=\frac {n\,c-\sum_{k=1}^n b_k}{y^{n+1}}+O\left(\frac{1}{y^{n+2}}\right)$$

However, may be, it could be possible to have a better approximation of $c$ and a function of the $b_k$ (to be explored later).

**An example for illustration**

Trying for $x=10^{20}$, $z=\pi$, $a=e$ and $b_k$ being the $k^{\text{th}}$ prime number, some results as a function of $n$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & y_0 & \text{solution} \\
 2 & 44.2276 &  44.2275 \\
 3 & 47.8232 &  47.8224 \\
 4 & 51.5652 &  51.5630 \\
 5 & 55.4718 &  55.4655 \\
 6 & 59.4969 &  59.4866 \\
 7 & 63.6580 &  63.6411 \\
 8 & 67.9169 &  67.8943 \\
 9 & 72.2904 &  72.2598 \\
 10 & 76.7898 &  76.7464 \\
 11 & 81.3617 &  81.3080 \\
 12 & 86.0407 &  85.9725 \\
 13 & 90.7989 &  90.7162 \\
 14 & 95.6140 &  95.5195 \\
 15 & 100.500 &  100.393 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Again, a couple of Newton iterations to polish the root will be more than sufficient.

For a maximum numerical efficiency, the function to be solved write
$$f(y)=(y+a)\log(z)-\sum_{k=1}^n \log(y+b_k)-\log(x)$$
$$f'(y)=\log(z)-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{y+b_k}$$

For the working case with $n=15$, $y_0=100.499980$, $y_1=100.393061$ while the solution is $y=100.393055$.

**Update**

Is *seems* that the approximation is not very sensitive to the value of $c$ since
$$\frac {\partial\, y_0}{\partial c}=\frac{n}{(y_0+c) \log (z)-n}$$

For example, in the last worked case for which $c=\frac{328}{15}$, at half this value $y=99.1089$ while doubling it gives $y=102.868$ in agreement with the theoretical slope of $0.12$.

I think that we can avoid the search of a "better" definition of $c$.