# Solving for x in logarithmic equation $\log_4(2x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 - 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I am trying to solve for $x$ in the equation $\log_4(2x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 - 1$. I have tried converting the logarithmic expression to exponential form, but I am not able to isolate $x$ in the resulting equation.

This is what I have tried as of now:

$$\log_4(2x) + \log_4(4) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$$

$$\log_4(8x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$$

$$2\log_4(8x) = x^2$$

$$\log_4(64x^2) = x^2$$

$$64x^2 = 4^{x^2}$$

after which I am not too sure on how to find x

Comment: It doesn't look like an equation you can solve without a computer. You will probably need some numerical method to find an approximate solution.

Comment: Taking the square root in a couple places and working backwards gives $\sqrt{\log_2 (8x)}=x$ which is all the simplification I believe is possible without resorting to the Lambert $W$ function...

Comment: Is there a reason why? any pattern that shows that it needs to be solved with an computer.

Comment: In general almost any equation you write up won’t have a solution you can compute by hand, so the question is not why but why not.

Comment: If you draw the graph of those two functions...then you'll see two points of intersection...one if them is two as we can easily solve for $64x^2=4^{x^2}$ ...it will give $x=\pm2$ but negative solution is not valid.....now the other point of intersection has to be numerically evaluated

Comment: $x=a^x$ is a typical equation that is known to almost always require numerical methods...

Comment: Do not worry about the special function. You will learn about it quite soon and I hope and wish that you will enjoy it (I felt in love with its 64 years ago). It is very use. On the search bar, just ype *Lambert* and notice 4158 entries. Cheers :-)

Comment: the reason why solving by rearranging with elementary functions isn't possible: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586412/how-can-we-show-that-az-ez-and-a-ln-z-z-have-no-elementary-inverse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*For your curiosity.*

You want to find the zeros of function
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{\log (2 x)}{\log (4)}-1$$
By insepection $x=2$ is a root

The first derivative
$$f'(x)=x-\frac{1}{x \log (4)}$$ cancels at $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log (4)}}$ and the second derivative test shows that this is a maximum.

Since $x >0$, rewrite
$$\log(2x)=\log(2)+\frac 12 \log(x^2)$$ and let $t=x^2$ to face
$$g(t)=2t \log(2)-\log(t)-6\log(2)$$ Th only explicit solution involves [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$t=-\frac{1}{2 \log (2)}W\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{32}\right)$$ Since the argument is small, use the series expansion (it is given in the linked page)
$$W(y)=y-y^2+\frac{3 y^3}{2}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ which will give
$$t \sim \frac{1}{64}+\frac{\log (2)}{2048}+\frac{3 \log ^2(2)}{131072}=0.0159744 \quad \implies \quad x=0.126390$$ while the exact solution is $x=0.126392 $.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_4{(2x)}=\frac{x^2}{2}-1$$

As stated already in a previous answer, try $x=2$:
$$x=2: \log_4{(2\cdot 2)}=\frac{2^2}{2}-1\Leftrightarrow 1=1$$

So $x=2$ is a solution. So far nothing new (from previous answer).

Next I would transform the equation into an exponential one:
$$\begin{align}\log_4{(2x)}&=\frac{1}{2}(1+\log_2 x)\\ \log_2 x&=x^2-3\\8x&=2^{x^2}\\f(x)&=2^{x^2}-8x\\f(0)&\gt 0, f(1)\lt 0\\f(0)&\gt 0, f(\frac{1}{2})\lt 0,…f(\frac{1}{8})\gt 0, f(\frac{3}{16})\lt 0\end{align}$$

I would continue to chase the root by halving the interval. So far I could tell that the root is located between $\frac{1}{8}$ and $\frac{3}{16}$.
[image: this plot was obtained using demos.com]
With red is $y=2^{x^2}$ and with blue is $y=8x$. The plot was obtained from desmos.com